# How can I load a jpg file into CBitmap (visual c++ 6.0)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How can I load a jpg into a CBitmap where I am using visual c++ 6.0 and don't have access to CImage?

thx

Comment: Most so-called C++ compilers aren't fully standard conforming, but MSVC 6 is so old and broken that it really doesn't deserve to be called a C++ compiler. UPGRADE! Also, realize that our answers to your questions may not work with VC6, as we here work with standard C++ that is three major revisions after, and 14 years younger than msvc6.

Comment: Some people are tied to platforms or tool chains that require VC6. Please don't be dismissive of other people's situations, especially not if you don't know anything about them/it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native way I know of. I've always used [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) for JPGs and PNGs - it's  robust and there's example code in the FAQ on how to load a PNG into an HBITMAP (which works exactly the same for a JPG).

One word of warning from experience - if you're storing your JPG as a resource, make sure you create a "JPG" resource type and store it as that, don't try and add it as a BITMAP resource or you'll have all sorts of problems trying to load it. I know it sounds obvious but it took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply call OleLoadPicturePath api to load not just jpg but other common formats also.

After loading it into the IPicture object you can call get_Handle to get the handle to HBITMAP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't, or at least, there isn't a build-in way. Have a look at CxImage, you can probably get that to work, especially when you only need jpg support.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of conversion is complex so i would reccoment using an external libary, take a look at [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/).

Answer (score 1):

```
CBitmap bmp;
HANDLE h = ::LoadImage(NULL, _T("c:\\MyImage.jpg"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
bmp.Attach(h);
```

Comment: can only loads bitmap, not jpg. I gave a pt for "LoadImage" as it is useful... thx

Comment: @jdl Have you tried it? I was going from memory yesterday, but here's the exact statement I have in my own code to open a JPEG: `m_hDIBSection = LoadImage(NULL, lpszPathName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);`

Comment: @jdl, my apologies, I think you are right and the program I copied that line from only works with BMP files. I may delete this answer.